# "Tooltip" jQuery plugin breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a very light "tooltip" jQuery plugin. Bellow is the code:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.tooltip = function() {

    return this.each(function(){

        var target = $(this);

        target.on("mouseover", function(event){
            var tooltip = $(document.createElement("div"));
            tooltip
                .html(target.attr("tooltip-text"))
                .addClass("tooltip")
                .css({
                     "top" : event.pageY, 
                     "left":event.pageX 
                     })
                .fadeIn(300);                               
        }); 

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

And I apply it like so:

```
<script>
    $("div.product").tooltip();
</script>
```

The idea is to have the tooltip appear when the user hovers the DIV, next to the cursor.
However, when I hover such a DIV (class "product"), the script crashes at the *.addClass("tooltip")* line:

***Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'addClass'***

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: instead of $(document.createElement("div")), try $(document).createElement("div")

Comment: You apply it outside of a document ready, and possibly before you include the tooltip script?

Comment: @Mike Robinson Actually I was, thanks for pointing that out. I've now included the call in the window.onload = function(){} block, but still the same problem. You can see it here: http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/

Comment: @AndreiOniga `var tooltip = $("<div />")` would be the "right" way instead of creating a dom node which is then converted to a jQuery element (and never added to the DOM). And you should use a `data-*` attribute instead of the custom `tooltip-text` - Nevertheless the code "works" - at least there is no error. http://jsfiddle.net/A2UZ4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're assigning the attribute tooltip-text:

```
  .html(target.attr("tooltip-text"))
```

The attribute is undefined, so it screws up the chaining of your jQuery events. Try doing this:

```
  .html(target.attr("tooltip-text") || "")
```

You also don't need to stick the execution in window.onload, putting it in a standard document ready will work fine.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know why but use

> .attr("style", tooltip.attr("style") + " tooltip")

instead of .addClass.

Hope this helps.